# When hard fault handler is not available or disabled will we get continous hard fault?

Tags: exception, arm, embedded

When hard fault handler is not available or disabled will we get continuous hard fault?
or does it occur when a condition which leads to fault occurs?

Comment: Is there any specific platform you're asking this question for?

Comment: yes.. specific to ARM

Comment: On ARM Cortex-M at least you cannot disable the hard-fault exception.  A basic run-time would set a default handler; normally a `B .` branch to self instruction. So you'd have to be more specific than "ARM" if you know of an ARM architecture where you can (seems unlikely).  Moreover is it is specific to an architecture, you need to fix the question, not leave it in a comment.  And be less random with your tags.  If you write an exception handler that simply returns without resolving the problem, then you, it would repeat the exception (I guess; who would do something that dumb).

Comment: there are multiple arm architectures, several. and three major boot/vector/exception schemes so you need to be more specific.  is this cortex-m?

Comment: the real question for cortex-m may be if the reset is defined and stack pointer, but other faults are 0xFFFFFFFF what does the logic do?  Otherwise you have defined something there and it will attempt to use it.  If your vectors do not have the lsbit set then what happens there as well...

Comment: without access to the source code/logic how would one tell if it hits it once and fails or hits it over and over again forever?